# Постепенная догрузка

Tags: android

Как можно реализовать постепенную догрузку, как в вконтакте. Т.е изначально подгрузилось небольшое количество эллементов, затем при скроле вниз подружалось такое же количество итемов, то есть шла постепенная подгрузка.
Извините, если некорректный вопрос, либо нарушил правила.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может быть это: [Android ListView dynamically Load more items when scroll to the Bottom](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-load-more-data.html).

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо большое

Comment: там ещё вроде был метод у listview (а может в другом классе), который дергается в onScroll и на основе ситуации решает - нужно ли догружать дальше или нет. Имя было похоже на `isCloseToEnd`, но могу нагуглить. Вроде видел в этом [видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo) с гугл IO.

Answer (score 2):

[Работающий Pull to refresh](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132277/)

> Это рассказ о том, как получилась работающая реализация `Pull to refresh` под `Android`. Совсем не будет примеров кода. Немного картинок и в конце статьи ссылка на архив проекта.

Comment: нет, вот например у меня большое количество эллементов например 100 листвьюшек, при запуске программы грузилось там всего 10, при скроле вниз, подгружались еще 10, частичная подгрузка..

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, можно смело считать ListView deprecated. Используйте RecyclerView и его ScrollListener:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview